# Wing in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry

Hi I'd like to do a plane wing in geometry nodes all is spline based but don't now how to make it more like wing shape more in image below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood you right, you want something like this?

[image]

The "trick" here is to use the curve radius. So you can shrinken your profile. I used a simple multiplier node here. Of course you could use a more complicated formula there.

Comment: Great this is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome